what is best approach to make high thrust from nozzle side? higher velocity or higher pressure?
Producing high thrust form jet engine is not one step. Actually, there are many factors that can significantly play rule here.
Anyway, am focusing only on the nozzle side and its rule only in my question and excluding all other parameters.
So, after the hot gases leave the high pressure turbine, in order to make highest thrust from the nozzle, what should we do? maintain higher pressure or higher velocity?

The answer to this question depends on whether you are considering an engine for a supersonic high performance aircraft -- or a subsonic aircraft that requires good fuel efficiency.
A subsonic aircraft will basically always have an exhaust that is subsonic at the nozzle exit.  In this situation, the nozzle exit pressure will match the ambient pressure.  This is called a fully expanded condition.  Matching this exit condition will actually determine the mass flow through the engine.
A supersonic aircraft will likely have an exhaust that is supersonic at the nozzle exit.  In this situation, the nozzle exit pressure will be either over-expanded (Pe<P0), under expanded (Pe>P0), or fully expanded (Pe=P0).  Under and over expanded nozzles will set up a pattern of shock diamonds, starting with either shocks or an expansion fan.  The fully expanded condition should not have diamonds in the exhaust.  In this case, flow will be choked at the nozzle throat -- which sets the mass flow through the engine.
The thrust equation for a jet is something like:
$Fn=\dot{m}\,(V_j-V_i)+(P_e-P_0)A_e$
You will get the best thrust when you are fully expanded ($P_e=P_0$) and therefore focus on $\Delta V$ -- i.e. maximize your $V_j$.

“A supersonic aircraft will likely have an exhaust that is supersonic at the nozzle exit” - Do you mean with an afterburner? I read somewhere that the speed of a jet exhaust is most of the time subsonic, unless there is an afterburner.

In order to have positive thrust, Vj > Vi.  So if the aircraft is supersonic, the exhaust must be too.  So we're left with the case of a supersonic capable aircraft that is flying subsonically at the time...  So, depending on the flight condition and most importantly the throttle level, it could be either way.  With AB engaged, you will have supersonic exhaust (even when flying subsonically).  But at part-power, you could have subsonic exhaust in a supersonic capable engine.

I see. So aircraft that are able to supercruise have supersonic exhaust speeds without the AB engaged? Interesting, thanks.
